# Error reading data into an array in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>    
#include<conio.h>

void main()    
{    
     int i,a[10],n;    
     printf("size of the array");    
     scanf("%d",&n);    

     printf("enter the elements");    
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)    
          scanf("%d",&a[i]);    
}
```

I am new to programming and I am stuck in this C program. The control is not entering the for loop.

Comment: What value are you entering for `n`, and if you print it's value is it correct?

Comment: where did you gave the value for `n`

Comment: now you need more more loop to print this value, just add this also `for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d", a[i]);`

Comment: To be able to debug a program yourself you might consider learn how to use a debugger and then use it. Btw, according to the C-Standard `main()` shall return `ìnt` not `void`.

Comment: I ran your program, it entered the `for` loop just fine. I entered `4` for the size, it let me type 4 numbers, then it exited. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: it works just fine as long as n is less than the length of the array. What are you trying to input?

Comment: Are you sure you recompiled after changing the code from a previous version?

Answer (score 3):

the code seems perfect, I think it's because of the compiler you are using. If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012/2013 make sure to use `scanf_s` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: This answer would fit better as a comment.

Comment: sorry but I tried to comment above it said I should have 50 reputation, I only have 5 :/

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't downvote - but be careful with such minimal answers, you can get downvotes easily.

Comment: Confirmed. Runs perfectly on Linux with GCC. I mean it enters the loop.

Comment: Congrats, you now have 50 rep ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This code should work, maybe you should print something out while you are reading to make it clearer, like this test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>    

int main()
{
    int i,a[10],n;
    printf("size of the array");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("enter the elements");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);    
        printf("> %d\n", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Running:

```
$ ./a.out 
size of the array3
enter the elements1 2 3
> 1
> 2
> 3
$ ./a.out 
size of the array3
enter the elements1
> 1
2
> 2
3
> 3
```